# How to put Style in the middle of a string?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlwings

Is it possible?

I'm using Openpyxl.

It's okay if it's a different library

EX:
[image]

Try:

```py
size_9_center_font = Font(name='Consolas', size=9, bold=True)
ws['A2'].font = title_font
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Openpyxl doesn't have released option to do this currently but you can do it with Xlwings using the characters attribute.

```
import xlwings as xw


wb = xw.Book('foo.xlsx')
ws = wb.sheets('Sheet1')

ws['A2'].value = "I want to put the style in the string"

ws['A2'].font.size = 9
ws['A2'].font.name = 'Consolas'

ws['A2'].characters[10:13].font.bold = True
ws['A2'].characters[18:23].font.color = (255, 0, 0)

wb.save()
wb.close()
```

[xlwings](/questions/tagged/xlwings)